# Middleware on specific page - NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, js-cookie

Well, I'm starting with nuxt and I have following routes:

```
/home

/dashboard

/login
```

I want to protect the `/dashboard`, but only for users logged in with a token in Cookie.

Then i created a middleware

```
/middleware/auth.js

import Cookie from 'js-cookie'

export default function({ req, redirect }) {
  if (process.server) {
    if (!req.headers.cookie) return redirect('/login')
    const jwtCookie = req.headers.cookie.split(';').find(c => c.trim().startsWith('jwt='))
    if (!jwtCookie) return redirect('/login')
  } else {
    const jwt = Cookie.get('jwt')
    if (!jwt) { window.location = '/login' }
  }
}
```

and register the middleware in my layout or dashboard page

```
<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'auth',
}
</script>
```

when I access `/dashboard` apparently works perfectly

but the problem is that the middleware is being registered globally, it is running on all pages, all routes

So when you access `/home` that is a published page, if you do not have the cookie, you end up being redirected to login page

anyone help?

Comment: it cant happen unless u have set your middleware globally in nuxt.config also

Comment: @Aldarund 
you're right, a simple error, I was not paying attention, I was many hours trying to do this server-side and client-side verification, I ended up sneaking that I had registered in nuxt.config.js, thank you

Comment: Maybe what you need it's to disable the auth middleware in a specific component, page or layout, i will recomend you to check the auth module documentation: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/middleware.html
In the example you can set `auth: false` to disable the auth middleware.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a condition based on the route.path param ?

```
export default function({ req, redirect, route }) {

  if (!route.path.includes('dashboard')) { // if path doesn't include "dashboard", stop there
    return;
  }

  if (process.server) {
    if (!req.headers.cookie) return redirect('/login')
    const jwtCookie = req.headers.cookie.split(';').find(c => c.trim().startsWith('jwt='))
    if (!jwtCookie) return redirect('/login')
  } else {
    const jwt = Cookie.get('jwt')
    if (!jwt) { window.location = '/login' }
  }
}
```

Therefore you still benefit from the pre-render middleware system.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have registered your `middleware/auth.js` in your `nuxt.config.js`.
When you register a middleware in `nuxt.config.js`, you're registering it globally, meaning it will be called for every route change.

Docs:
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you should call them `plugin`, because of
middleware called by each route changed also you can't use middleware in layout and subComponent, you can use it as `plugin` and call it manually everywhere also it's reactive and runtime.

```
 path: /plugind/auth.js

 import Cookie from 'js-cookie';

 export default function({ req, redirect }) {
 if (process.server) {
   if (!req.headers.cookie) return redirect('/login')
    const jwtCookie = req.headers.cookie.split(';').find(c => 
    c.trim().startsWith('jwt='))
    if (!jwtCookie) return redirect('/login')
    } else {
    const jwt = Cookie.get('jwt')
   if (!jwt) { window.location = '/login'
   }
  }
 }
```